# NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler crash

Tags: iphone, crash

Why am I getting `NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler` crash all of a sudden in my code. I am blank why this crash popped up all of a sudden and how to squash it.

Comment: Can you at least provide some code so we can try to further understand your issue?

Comment: is there really no capitalization/CamelCasing in "nsfastenumerationmutationhandler"?

Comment: @Luke,Sujith: It's a hude code base, and am not sure where exactly its breaking. I think an NSZombieEnabled could do the trick and get me the point where it breaks.

Comment: @Phresnel: Yeah of course it was in camel case `NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler`, but I just put it in double quotes, so that most of you can understand.

Comment: @manoj: My eyes are really insensible to all-lowercase strings longer than the Llama can spit. And it somehow is a form of mis-quotation in case-sensitive environments. I'll edit it :)

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x610000859410> was mutated while being enumerated.'

Comment: This question show have been closed under the official close reason of lacking a [mcve]. I shall try to do that now.

Answer (score 14):

**Crash Error:**
 **** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** **Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x610000859410> was mutated while being enumerated**.'*

You must be trying to change an array while you using fast enumeration.

**Example**

```
for ( id anObject in anArray ) {
    if ( /* anObject satisfies some condition */ ) {
        [anArray removeObject:anObject];
    }
}
```

That shouldn't be done. Use a different array or probably `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` method to filter. Remedy, however, depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Deepak, I had gone through some referred links from google, few guys have narrated the same thing. Now, the biggest problem is, mine has got a huge code base, not sure though where am trying to change the array using fast enumeration. I mean do you think, this not the best practice to do so, and in between I will try your suggested way.

Comment: It's not a question of best practice. You can't just do it as it will raise an exception as you are seeing. Refer [`this doc`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html). As for the code I posted, it is not a fix. It illustrates the error. Yeah, if you are trying to use a different array then that is one of the options to go forward with.

Comment: However, if this is happening suddenly then this must be recent change . Investigate this by doing `bt` or `backtrace` (in full) in the debugger. Post the output. You will have a fair idea where the error is.

Comment: Do you think by any way the error/crash can be reproducible? As I am trying to reproduce it but without any success.

Comment: `backtrace` in the console isn't giving you anything?

Comment: thanks, this was very applicable to my issue and a good catch, as the original question doesn't give any example code

Answer (score 3):

Came here looking for a solution and ended up taking a copy of the original array to get around the issue.

```
for (NSObject *object in [array copy]) {
    if(condition) {
        [array removeObject....]
        break;
    }
}
```