# NSArray was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm creating a level game where each level is loaded in by presenting a new scene. When opening the project on a physical device it will crash half of the time saying NSArray was mutated while being enumerated. I think it has to do with my animationManger class which loads in multiple SKTextureAtlases into collections and then makes SKActions to animate each node in the scene. I put the Animation Manager in the GameViewController so the textures wouldn't have to be loaded in each time a new level is presented. Can someone give me some advice on what to do

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    var AnimManager:AnimationManager?
    var LvlManager:LevelManager?
    var sceneView:SKView = SKView()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       //Load these 2
       AnimManager = AnimationManager(sets: ["Launcher","Button","Launch"])
       LvlManager = LevelManager(levels: 46)

       NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.createScene), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "CreateScene"), object: nil)

       //Create the SceneView
       sceneView = self.view as! SKView
       //Scene View Properties
       sceneView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
       sceneView.showsFPS = true
       sceneView.showsNodeCount = true
       sceneView.showsPhysics = true
   }  

   func createScene() {

       //Create the new Scene
       let scene = PilScene(Size: UIScreen.main.bounds.size, DataFile: "Levels", levelManager: LvlManager!, animationManager: AnimManager!)
       //Present the Scene
       print("presenting scene")
       sceneView.presentScene(scene)
   }

   override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
       return true
   }

   override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
       if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
           return .allButUpsideDown
       } else {
           return .all
       }
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
   }

   override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
       return true
   }
}
```

Below is the Class that creates all the animation actions for the nodes in each scene

```
 class AnimationManager {

//Tuple contains Name of FrameSet, Forward Animation Action, and Backward Animation Action
var actions:[(String, SKAction, SKAction)] = []

//Starts loading the atlases when the manager is initialized
init(sets: [String]) {
    loadAtlases(setNames: sets)
}

//Creates the atlases and preloads them immediately
func loadAtlases(setNames: [String]) {

    for name in setNames {

        let atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: name)

        atlas.preload {
            self.createFrameSetAction(atlas: atlas, atlasName: name)
            if name == setNames[setNames.count - 1] {
                print("Game Finished Loading")
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "CreateScene"), object: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

//Takes in the atlases and creates collections of sktextures
func createFrameSetAction(atlas: SKTextureAtlas, atlasName: String) {

    var frameCollection:[SKTexture] = []

    var loop = 0

    while loop <= atlas.textureNames.count - 1 {
        if loop < 10 {
            frameCollection.append(atlas.textureNamed("Frames_0000\(loop)"))
        }else if loop < 100{
            frameCollection.append(atlas.textureNamed("Frames_000\(loop)"))
        }else if loop > 99 && loop < 110 {
            frameCollection.append(atlas.textureNamed("Frames_00\(loop)"))
        }else{
            frameCollection.append(atlas.textureNamed("Frames_00\(loop)"))
        }
        loop += 1
    }

    let animate = SKAction.animate(with: frameCollection, timePerFrame: 1/30)
    let reverseAnimate = animate.reversed()
    actions.append((atlasName, animate,reverseAnimate))
}

//Returns a collection of frames for a texture set by its name
func getAnimation(name: String) -> SKAction {

    for action in actions { 
        if name == action.0 { 
            return action.1 
        }
    }

    return SKAction.animate(with: [SKTexture(imageNamed: name)], timePerFrame: 1/30)
    }
}
```

Here is what it is saying in the console:

```
    2017-01-18 12:50:23.226 PilaTesting[7289:186676] *** Terminating app      due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '***     Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x610000646750> was mutated while being enumerated.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001076ccd4b  __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010712e21e objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107735f6c __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 124
3   SpriteKit                           0x0000000108247b6d -[SKNode _processSearchTokens:visited:usingBlock:stopPointer:] + 2440
4   SpriteKit                           0x0000000108247082 -[SKNode _enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:stopPointer:] + 1127
5   SpriteKit                           0x000000010824695a -[SKNode enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:] + 58
6   SpriteKit                           0x0000000108246868 -[SKNode childNodeWithName:] + 148
7   PilaTesting                         0x0000000106afe470 _TFC11PilaTesting9PilaScene6updatefSdT_ + 112
8   PilaTesting                         0x0000000106afe65c _TToFC11PilaTesting9PilaScene6updatefSdT_ + 44
9   SpriteKit                           0x000000010820fe37 -[SKScene _update:] + 365
10  SpriteKit                           0x000000010822ee19 -[SKView _update:] + 950
11  SpriteKit                           0x000000010822b682 __51-[SKView _vsyncRenderForTime:preRender:postRender:]_block_invoke.322 + 285
12  SpriteKit                           0x000000010822aa4a -[SKView _vsyncRenderForTime:preRender:postRender:] + 611
13  SpriteKit                           0x000000010822c2b6 __29-[SKView setUpRenderCallback]_block_invoke + 211
14  SpriteKit                           0x0000000108263e73 -[SKDisplayLink _callbackForNextFrame:] + 335
15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010e68b895 _ZN2CA7Display15DisplayLinkItem8dispatchEy + 57
16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010e68b755 _ZN2CA7Display11DisplayLink14dispatch_itemsEyyy + 449
17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010765edb4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010765ea43 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1075
19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010765e5ca __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 250
20  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001076562f1 __CFRunLoopRun + 2065
21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107655884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
22  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010edc9a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
23  UIKit                               0x000000010842fc68 UIApplicationMain + 159
24  PilaTesting                         0x0000000106b029ff main + 111
25  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010b78068d start + 1
26  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: " it will crash" on what line?

Comment: @matt It doesn't show specific line, just says terminating due to collection being mutated while being enumerated.

Comment: Oh, I doubt that. You need to look at where we are when we terminate. Also, you might like to copy the entire console output and paste it into your question.

Comment: @matt,  it is not a crash, the program terminated, which means it probably   sets the point of last execution to the AppDelegate class, so MuffinMan would not be able to pin point it

Comment: I am going to guess it is your actions array that is being mutated

Comment: @Knight0fDragon "The program terminated" — that is what a crash _is_.

Comment: program terminating and a crash are 2 different things, a crash halts execution when in a debug state, a program terminating ends the program

Comment: @Muffinman2497 create an exception breakpoint by Debug > Breakpoints > Create Exception Breakpoint...

Comment: Guys why downvoting this question. The OP is obviously not familiar with a debugging so he doesnt have an idea how to find problematic line. What 0x141e said is the way to go.

Comment: @Whirlwind I updated the question to show what the console is saying.

Comment: @Muffinman2497 Do what 0x141e said and you will get the exact line. It seems that you enumerate nodes by name in your update: method. So search for that part.

Comment: So you are likely doing this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6608439/3402095 Still it doesnt have to be that. I've seen some complains that if you remove node from its parent while enumerating you will get this crash. Never tried though.

Comment: The former case make sense for me because when you remove node from a tree you are likely removing it from the place that is being searched, means you are modifying current collection, thus the error (i dont know how SpriteKit internally works though becuase that is ukoown for us currently, so I cant comment more precisely).

Comment: Same goes with any kind off mutating some array, eg. using addChild() which adds node to a tree. Still these are speculations and you will get your answer when you find line that crashes.

Comment: Where are you calling `childNodeWithName`  I do not see that in the code provided

Comment: @Muffinman2497 looks like the crash is in an `update` method in an `SKScene` subclass (such as `GameScene`).

Comment: @0x141E yeah that was the problem, I didn't include Gamescene because I didn't think it was part of the problem.

Comment: well it shouldnt be `GameScene`, it should be `PilScene`,  or are you considering these the same?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon sorry for the confusion. Yes, I meant them as the same.

Comment: @Muffinman2497 Lol I meant to say latter case, rather than former. Anyways, it seems you figured out which is the line that crashes, right ?